# Comparing data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm an rookie PHP/SQL'er and I'm working on a little project, and one of the things that is required - is to be able to print a name for an ID, for example - *ID 1* gets printed as *Night*

I have two tables, one which holds all the IDs and Names.

```
+--+------+
|ID|Names |
+--+------+
|1 |Name 1|
+--+------+
|2 |Name 2|
+--+------+
|3 |Name 3|
+--+------+
```

and another table that holds 2 sets of IDs and some extra stuff.

```
+---+---+------+--------+
|ID1|ID2|Upvote|Downvote|
+---+---+------+--------+
|1  |2  |0     |0       |
+---+---+------+--------+
|2  |3  |0     |0       |
+---+---+------+--------+
|3  |1  |0     |0       |
+---+---+------+--------+
```

I currently use:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM champion_counters WHERE Champion_ID='" . $search_resultC . "'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Champion_ID'] . " " . $row['Counter_ID'] . " " . $row['Up_Votes'] . " " . $row['Down_Votes'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
```

to print a table of the ID1 with all of the other IDs under ID2, So I wondered if there were a way to compare an ID to a Name in a different table, and still be able to print a full list? (example of the current state: http://goo.gl/zxkfQQ )

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
          WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.Champion_ID='" . $search_resultC . "'");
```

This will output only rows with similar ID's in both tables, modify it as you wish.